# Strange issue with nginx proxy upstream and ssh port forwarding

Tags: linux, nginx, ssh, iptables, linux-networking

We were using nginx legacy till now, but we upgraded our system to 1.6.2 recently.

We have a port forwarding of ssh as well as load balanced nginx server for two separate internal servers.

The mentioned configuration was working till recently but not now, http working fine but port forwarding for ssh not working.

We are amazed to see how port forwarding is related to nginx.

Nginx Conf

```
   upstream web_rack {
        server 192.168.1.10:80;
        server 192.168.1.11:80;
   }
```

Iptables forwarding

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:2001
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2002 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.11:2001
```

Now, with above configuration we are unable to ssh the servers, but if we comment out one of the upstream server, we are able to log into it.

```
   upstream web_rack {
   #     server 192.168.1.10:80;
        server 192.168.1.11:80;
   }
```

With above configuration, with nginx service restarted, we are able to login via ssh into `192.168.1.10`

Comment: It's not clear how nginx and ssh are related?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Exactly what my issue is, logically it should not be related to each other. Events are captured via tcpdump utility. If there is issue with iptables, events should not occur.

Comment: Anyone who came across such issue.